# remove htmlentities and leave just text and space using urlencode

Tags: php, url, seo, urlencode, html-entities

Am creating a SEO friendly url using the following script;

```
str_replace("%2F", "+", urlencode(@mynameis 'JaySmoke' and I love (Stackoverflow)))
```

When I check the address generated, it gives me the following;

```
%40mynameis+%27JaySmoke%27+and+I+love+%28Stackoverflow%29
```

As you can see, the urlencode has also encoded the htmlentities, I wanted to know if there's a way to tell it to ignore all htmlentities and just encode the space and text like;

```
myname+is+JaySmoke+and+I+love+Stackoverflow
```

Answer (score 1):

A preg_replace should suffice

```
preg_replace("@%.{2}@", '', $string)
```

Which simply replaces % plus any 2 characters

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't do what I asked for. It's stopped the conversion alright but I want it to remove them all and leave just the letters which are joined together by either a plus or minus. Kind of like what you see on url used for this page.

Comment: solved. preg_replace("@%.{2}@", '', urlencode($string);

Answer (score 0):

A late answer here

```
<?php
//$string represents a string text that might contain unwanted characters
$string = $_POST['text-with-all-kind-of-characters'];

//remove all unwanted characters
$res = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/", " ", $string);

//remove extra spaces within the text
$untrimmed = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $res);

//remove extra spaces at ends of string
$trimmed = trim($untrimmed);

//replace all remaining spaces with dash
$urltitle =  str_replace(" ", "+", "$trimmed");

//our final product 
echo $urltitle;


?>
```